# to lower case in array_combine

Tags: php, csv, lowercase

I have a simple parser that parse a csv file and return me an array indexed by the names of the cells in the header row, here is my code :

```
$file = file(public_path() .'/screens/'. $file, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

$csv = array_map("str_getcsv", $file, array_fill(0, count($file), ';'));
$keys = array_shift($csv);
$response = (object)array();
foreach ($csv as $i => $row) {
  // Combine headers with values
  $csv[$i] = array_combine($keys, $row);
  $wellName = $csv[$i]["Well"];
  $response->{$wellName} = array_combine($keys, $row);
}
return $response;
```

My problem is that in my csvfiles sometimes the headers have an uppercase at the beggining or in the word, but I don't know where I am supposed to do my strtolower in my parsing function, I want that only the headers are in lower cases.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're already using array_map, any time you want to transform values in an structure, you should look into a map function.

```
$keys = array_map('strtolower', array_shift($csv));
```

Answer (score 2):

As keys are in `$keys`, you can map `strtolower` function to `$keys` only once:

```
$keys = array_shift($csv);
$keys = array_map('strtolower', $keys);
```